2GB Raspberry Pi in headless mode — only 1.80 GB usable
htop:
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||                            215M/1.80G]

~200 MB are perhaps being used for graphics? How do I disable or reduce graphics RAM?
Update: Following the link to config.txt documentation kindly provided by @goldilocks, I've set gpu_mem=16 (the default is 76) and it did, as expected, increase my available memory by ~50 MB to 1.85 GB.
About 128 MB are still missing somewhere.
Can something called cma be responsible for this? When I run raspinfo, I get:

...
Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x000000002a000000, size 64 MiB
...
Memory: 1855800K/2070528K available (13376K kernel code, 2210K rwdata, 4264K rodata, 4864K init, 1083K bss, 149192K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved)
...

It looks like CMA eats 64 MB. Is this also reducible? What about the other missing 64 MB? And what is 149192K reserved (0.14 GB)?

why do you believe that 200 MB is used for graphics?  ... Linux requires memory

You can get the amount dedicated to the gpu w/ vcgencmd get_mem gpu.   You can set this via (legacy) memory options in config.txt; there is  minimum, 16 (MiB) is fine for a Pi 4 although this may "disable certain GPU features" (GUI desktop will still work, at least w/ Xorg).

Thank you, everyone! The gpu_mem worked but ~128 MB are still missing. I've updated the question.

Why do you care? Are you short of memory for some task? Why get 2GB RAM for a headless system? You are obviously running an old OS.

The kernel memory management reserves memory for the hardware drivers. Especially the block devices (e.g. SD_Card) need some memory for buffers. And of cause the gpu and camera module need a lot. If a driver is installed the memory is need. This does not depend on the fact that you use it or not.
The CMA asures that you have enough memory in a big chunk for processes (kernel and user) that require a lot of contigous memory. Escpecially if dma is involved. You can switch off CMA but that could result in crashes for e.g. gstreamer, web server, nfs.

I'm not really sure, but change the reserved memory requires rebuilding the kernel and removing kernel modules also. I'm also not sure if it worth it, just to save a few MByte of RAM compared to 2 GByte of available RAM.

First up, there is nothing weird, nefarious, or inefficient going on here.  The memory stats you get in userspace (eg. via htop) are userspace stats, and it is a basic premise of modern OS design that 100% of physical RAM is not userspace memory.  That a whopping ~6% of the ostensible amount of RAM (2048 MiB) is set aside by the kernel is hardly a means for concern, and (IMO, which is pretty sound), not something you should pursue rectifying.
Along the same lines:

It looks like CMA eats 64 MB. Is this also reducible?

You might want to look up what CMA is for first, because this amount is not, AFAIK (but I could be wrong) deducted from userspace memory, it is part of userspace memory, and in any case plays an important role in the system.  64 MB is actually low; this is on a Pi 4 4GB running bullseye, kernel 6.1.21-v8+:
> dmesg | grep Memory
41:[    0.000000] Memory: 3408044K/4102144K available (
    11776K kernel code, 2106K rwdata, 3688K rodata,
    4160K init, 1077K bss, 169812K reserved, 524288K cma-reserved)

> raspinfo | grep CMA
649:[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x000000000ec00000,
                   size 512 MiB

(Those are actually both in the dmesg buffer, which raspinfo samples at some point.)
That 512 MiB "cma-reserved" seems to a standard amount determined by the linux kernel (it's the same on my beefy x86-64 desktop) and I would guess all other modern OS's pursue a similiar strategy -- and again, presuming it is considered part of userspace, does not account for your "missing" mem (RaspiOS bookworm reports 320 MiB on a 4GB Pi 5 w/ kernel 6.6.28+rpt-rpi-2712, so likely this varies based on total RAM or you are using a different distro).
You can set the CMA volume (including to zero) via the kernel command line, using the cma= option in /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt, be sure that file remains all one line: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.2/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html#:~:text=cma%3Dnn%5BMG%5D%40%5Bstart,%2Flinux%2Fdma%2Dcontiguous.
Again, though, that's not going to change the amount of "missing" userspace if it is already considered part of such, and what it will likely result in practical terms, if anything, is a performance reduction.
WRT to what that missing RAM is being used for, try starting up htop, select the MEM% column, then click it again to reverse the listing so you are seeing the processes using the least userspace at the top.  If this list doesn't start with a dozen or so things with 0 in the VIRT and RES column, press shift-K to show kernel threads.
Those kthreads do not really occupy no physical memory, of course.  It is just that the memory they occupy is kernel space, ie., part of that "missing" 128 MiB or whatever.  As a casual observation, on my desktop dmesg also reports:
kernel: x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB

That seems to be coming from the x86 based memory-management (mm) subsystem, but I doubt it is all that different on ARM/Pis/etc. because the determining factor will be much less the amount of memory available and much more the requirements of the software including the kernel.  Generally speaking, a cross-platform piece of software will use about the same amount of RAM to accomplish the same tasks on all platforms (or at least, the variance won't be orders of magnitude, the way system RAM can be).1
So you might as well just consider that 128 MiB kernel space and leave it at that.  There probably are tools out there allowing you to break down how it is used further, but this is unlikely to be of interest unless you are researching kernel architecture.  Believing that this memory is somehow wasted and needs recovering might be akin to believing your car has too many wheels: 1) If you really want that, you are going to need to buy a whole new car, because taking them off the one you have... 2) Even if you pursue the whole new car angle, getting the number of wheels down by more than 25% is going to be a very tall order.


The primary reason the kernel would set aside a block this way rather than allocate it dynamically from some common user/kernel space pool is that doing the latter would be a somewhat pointless performance hit.


AFAIK Bullseye does not allocate CMA.

Which is why that dmesg from a Pi 4 running bullseye reports "524288K cma-reserved" at boot...  While digging into this a bit further though I found a kernel option to set or eliminate the CMA volume (edited in).

Oops I meant Bookworm; I know Bullseye used it. Dumb idea starting new OS with same letter!

:/ Yet (as per above) "RaspiOS bookworm reports 320 MiB on a 4GB Pi 5 w/ kernel 6.6.28+rpt-rpi-2712"...  I can't see why it would not be using CMA -- it has nothing to do with hardware, so there is no particular reason to be concerned about it specifically on ARM or RPIs.
